# How to add a hyperlink which opens a text file into a folder of a document Library

Tags: document-library, folder, hyperlink, file

I've a requirement to add a link to a txt file in a folder of a document library such that user who want to upload content to the folder may click on the link which will open the file in a separate window then the user may close it and continue in the SharePoint site, The link should be located above the list of document of the folder and not at the same level as the document in the folder

**From my reading the only way to do that was:**
      -To  go to the folder itself, edit the page , then add the content editor text and click to edit a text in. at this point I  noticed that after having added the content editor into the page of the folder The document library containing the folder doesn't provide anymore a Library Tab where with may access library settings which a problem for me as i need to set a lot of thing on the document library. **My 1st questions , it is this normal? if yes how to access the library settings of that library after having add a content editor a page view of a folder in that library?**

A part from that  i kept trying my initial solution which was to add a link to the page view of a folder of that library. **and here I have 2 options**:

1. **add a link using the link icon**: with this solution I need the exact URL that open the txt file, I tried uploading the txt in the
   site asset, But I was able to get only the link the site asset, and
   need 2 clicks to read the txt file. **Where should I normally upload
   the txt file in sharepoint in order to have a url that I can use to
   directly open the file? After having downloaded the file how to get
   the URL address that irectly open that file to use in the link
   creation?**
2. **Or add a document** : with this option, when I click on the created lik yes it open the txt file in a browser and in the current
   tab, unfortunately after having read the txt document If I click on
   the back arrow in the browser to get back to the sharepoint site I
   get the error that the website has expired.
   **Is there anyway to access the document in another tab and keep the sharepoint site open? how can I add a content editor to a document
   library page without disable the Library toold tab?**

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got a partial answer to my multiple questions in this post: 
  -The explanation gave above is the way to go, I saved the file I want the link on in Site Assets and copy the URL toward the file. when adding the link in the content editor in the page, in the link tools tab appearing when adding a link, there is a check box to allow the link to be open in another  tab and even to show picture of the file.-**So at this point my link is above the list of document and doesn't get mix up with the document in the folder,  and the link open the file in another tab**

**But still the document library where the link appear is not showing anymore the library tab as before, which is needed as there are things that I would set up in the library setting using the library tab and the link appear in any part/ folder of the library and not only in the folder.**